# Find missing dates (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I have one table that contain d_date column. In this column, contain date value only.

My question is "I want to find missing dates from this column(d_date)".

example: 
This column contains dates from "1-Jan-2007" to "7-Jan-2007" 
then i want to find missing date between "1-Jan-2007" to "10-Jan-2007" 
and my result should be "8-Jan-2007", "9-Jan-2007", "10-Jan-2007".

So, how can i get this result?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can compare a date series created with the function `generate_series(start, stop, step interval)`  to dates in your table:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2007-01-01', '2007-01-10', interval '1 day') AS dates
  WHERE dates NOT IN (SELECT d_date FROM your_table);
```

More info on function `generate_series` from PostgreSQL documentation: [9.24. Set Returning Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WITH RECURSIVE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) to build a table of dates and then select dates that are not in your table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(d) AS (
  (SELECT '2015-01-01'::date)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT d + 1 FROM t WHERE d + 1 <= '2015-01-10')
) SELECT d FROM t WHERE d NOT IN (SELECT d_date FROM tbl);
```

**Edit:** notice that a recursive CTE might be an overkill here. [Epikuros's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28583637/1892060) provides a simpler solution with `generate_series`.

Comment: No need for the recursive CTE - `generate_series()` will be more efficient

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true. Editing.