# How to get Postgres to return 0 for empty rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which get data summarised between two dates like so:

```
SELECT date(created_at),
COUNT(COALESCE(id, 0))                                                                      AS total_orders,
   SUM(COALESCE(total_price, 0))                                                               AS total_price,
   SUM(COALESCE(taxes, 0))                                                                     AS taxes,
   SUM(COALESCE(shipping, 0))                                                                  AS shipping,
   AVG(COALESCE(total_price, 0))                                                               AS average_order_value,
   SUM(COALESCE(total_discount, 0))                                                            AS total_discount,
   SUM(total_price - COALESCE(taxes, 0) - COALESCE(shipping, 0) - COALESCE(total_discount, 0)) as net_sales
FROM orders
WHERE shop_id = 43
  AND orders.active = true
  AND orders.created_at >= '2022-07-20'
  AND orders.created_at <= '2022-07-26'
GROUP BY date (created_at)
order by created_at::date desc
```

However for dates that do not have any orders, the query returns nothing and I'd like to return `0`.

I have tried with `COALESCE` but that doesn't seem to do the trick?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What date value do you want to return in the case of a 0 count?

Comment: Use `generate_seies` and `left join` to the resultant list of dates.

Comment: You can use a simple nested query and count the resulting rows if it's 0 pick the default values in the outer query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `0` would be ideal. I'm making a graph with the result, so I can't have missing dates.

Comment: This sounds like something you should handle in the presentation layer which is calling Postgres.  Just check for an empty result set, in that case, render a different graph.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock & visrey do you have an example?

Comment: I'm formatting in the presentation layer but I'd like at least an empty array (or zero or similar) to so I can replace with what I need for the graph. Currently, if I query for the last week and only 1 day has orders, I only get one array and to fill the array with remaining dates is becoming expensive (this is for a dashboard and there are many similar queries)

Comment: A table definition showing data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE orders ...`) would be instrumental. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the below script.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT date(created_at) AS created_at,
         COUNT(id) AS total_orders,
         SUM(total_price) AS total_price,
         SUM(taxes) AS taxes,
         SUM(shipping) AS shipping,
         AVG(total_price) AS average_order_value,
         SUM(total_discount) AS total_discount,
         SUM(total_price - taxes - shipping - total_discount) AS net_sales
    FROM orders
    WHERE shop_id = 43
        AND orders.active = true
        AND orders.created_at >= '2022-07-20'
        AND orders.created_at <= '2022-07-26'
    GROUP BY  date (created_at)
UNION
SELECT dates AS created_at,
         0 AS total_orders,
         0 AS total_price,
         0 AS taxes,
         0 AS shipping,
         0 AS average_order_value,
         0 AS total_discount,
         0 AS net_sales
FROM generate_series('2022-07-20', '2022-07-26', interval '1 day') AS dates
WHERE dates NOT IN 
    (SELECT created_at
    FROM orders
    WHERE shop_id = 43
        AND orders.active = true
        AND orders.created_at >= '2022-07-20'
        AND orders.created_at <= '2022-07-26' ) ) a
ORDER BY  created_at::date desc;
```

There is one sample for your reference.
[Sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6d3812b3a76353a85a95a9f85ee4d9d1)

I got your duplicate test cases at my side. The root cause is created_at field (datattype:timestamp), hence there are duplicate lines.

Below script is correct for your request.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT date(created_at) AS created_at,
         COUNT(id) AS total_orders,
         SUM(total_price) AS total_price,
         SUM(taxes) AS taxes,
         SUM(shipping) AS shipping,
         AVG(total_price) AS average_order_value,
         SUM(total_discount) AS total_discount,
         SUM(total_price - taxes - shipping - total_discount) AS net_sales
    FROM orders
    WHERE shop_id = 43
        AND orders.active = true
        AND orders.created_at >= '2022-07-20'
        AND orders.created_at <= '2022-07-26'
    GROUP BY  date (created_at)
UNION
SELECT dates AS created_at,
         0 AS total_orders,
         0 AS total_price,
         0 AS taxes,
         0 AS shipping,
         0 AS average_order_value,
         0 AS total_discount,
         0 AS net_sales
FROM generate_series('2022-07-20', '2022-07-26', interval '1 day') AS dates
WHERE dates NOT IN 
    (SELECT date (created_at)
    FROM orders
    WHERE shop_id = 43
        AND orders.active = true
        AND orders.created_at >= '2022-07-20'
        AND orders.created_at <= '2022-07-26' ) ) a
ORDER BY  created_at::date desc;
```

Here is a sample that's same with your side. [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=86111b6c1c4d1db4a0d0b69690b7837e)

Comment: you suggestion looks promising but it repeats the dates (for the ones where there are orders, I have two rows, one with data and one empty)

Comment: Please use the corrected script.

Comment: still shows duplicated. There was a duplicated `ORDER BY` which I removed as it was causing an error. Could have it been related?

Comment: Sorry. `ORDER BY` is duplicate. I modify “Union All” to "Union" for your case. Also, I create some data for testing, refer to them,

Comment: Thanks for the help and no need to apologise. I still get the duplicates though  :/

Answer (score 2):

This should be **substantially faster** - and **correct**:

```
SELECT *
     , total_price - taxes - shipping - total_discount AS net_sales  -- ⑤
FROM  (
   SELECT created_at
        , COALESCE(total_orders        , 0) AS total_orders
        , COALESCE(total_price         , 0) AS total_price
        , COALESCE(taxes               , 0) AS taxes
        , COALESCE(shipping            , 0) AS shipping
        , COALESCE(average_order_value , 0) AS average_order_value
        , COALESCE(total_discount      , 0) AS total_discount
   FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2022-07-20'  -- ①
                        , timestamp '2022-07-26'
                        , interval '1 day') AS g(created_at)
   LEFT  JOIN (  -- ③
      SELECT created_at::date
           , count(*)            AS total_orders  -- ⑥
           , sum(total_price)    AS total_price
           , sum(taxes)          AS taxes
           , sum(shipping)       AS shipping
           , avg(total_price)    AS average_order_value
           , sum(total_discount) AS total_discount
      FROM   orders
      WHERE  shop_id = 43
      AND    active  -- simpler
      AND    created_at >= '2022-07-20'
      AND    created_at <  '2022-07-27'  -- ② !
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) o USING (created_at)  -- ④
   ) sub
ORDER  BY created_at DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2502c9b0a541bae2cef04260f20c8ba1)*

I copied, simplified, and extended Xu's fiddle for comparison.

① Why this particular form for `generate_series()`? See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

② Assuming `created_at` is data type `timestamp` your original formulation is most probably incorrect. `created_at <= '2022-07-26'` would include the first instant of '2022-07-26' and exclude the rest. To include all of '2022-07-26', use `created_at <  '2022-07-27'`. See:

- [How do I write a function in plpgsql that compares a date with a timestamp without time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62004811/how-do-i-write-a-function-in-plpgsql-that-compares-a-date-with-a-timestamp-witho/62020050#62020050)

③ The `LEFT JOIN` is the core feature of this answer. Generate all days with `generate_series()`, independently aggregate days from table `orders`, *then* `LEFT JOIN` to retain one row per day like you requested.

④ I made the column name match `created_at`, so we can conveniently shorten the join syntax with the `USING` clause.

⑤ Compute `net_sales` in an outer `SELECT` *after* replacing NULL values, so we need `COALESCE()` only once.

⑥ `count(*)` is equivalent to `COUNT(COALESCE(id, 0))` in any case, but cheaper. See:

- [Optimizing GROUP BY + COUNT DISTINCT on unnested jsonb column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038210/optimizing-group-by-count-distinct-on-unnested-jsonb-column/63038532#63038532)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WITH RECURSIVE to build a table of dates and then select dates that are not in your table

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(d) AS (
  (SELECT '2015-01-01'::date)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT d + 1 FROM t WHERE d + 1 <= '2015-01-10')
) SELECT d FROM t WHERE d NOT IN (SELECT d_date FROM tbl);
```

[look on this post : ][1]

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583379/find-missing-dates-postgresql#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20WITH%20RECURSIVE,SELECT%20d_date%20FROM%20tbl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583379/find-missing-dates-postgresql#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20WITH%20RECURSIVE,SELECT%20d_date%20FROM%20tbl))%3B

Comment: `generate_series()` is much easier to use and probably more efficient as well